# How is time measured in the galaxy far far away?

Tags: star-wars

I understand that the galaxy has a synchronized form of keeping time. It's almost always referred to as standard time. A standard day, week, year etc. They would need that since a a day, week, or year will vary from planet to planet. So my question is, **What is the Galactic Calendar Synced to?**

I thought it might be the rotation of Courescant since it's the capital of the Republic and the Empire, but I'm not sure.

I would also like to know **when the Galactic Calender was established**.

Comment: This looks like a dupe, based on @Hatandboots because it covers your questions in the answer.